# Importing multiple emails into distribution group in Microsoft Exchange on Windows Server

Tags: windows, email, windows-server-2008, exchange

I've got some email addresses in *.xlsx file (about 300) and I want to import them into one distribution group in Microsoft Exchange.

The problem is some emails has already got a corresponding contact on my server (about a half of those emails) and other doesn't.

What's the easiest (or most elegant) way to add all those mails into distribution group? I don't want to check if 300 email addresses have their contact and then adding it all.

Comment: Have you tried exporting the existing group emails first into excel [Export Distribution Group Members in Microsoft Exchange 2010](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Export-Distribution-Group-0462cb22) then using excel to look for emails in one list and not in the other?

Comment: that's actually great idea, but when I import al contacts is there a way to add all contacts I want to group?

Comment: See [Add users to a distribution group from a .csv file in exchange 2007\2010 Powershell](http://johnacook.wordpress.com/2010/04/19/add-users-to-a-distribution-group-from-a-csv-file-in-exchange-20072010-powershell/)